# How to style using TemplatedControl within ItemsControl ItemTemplate

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make a TemplatedControl with multiple ControlTemplate and DataTemplates. Mainly this TemplatedControl will have a few ItemsControls. Now I'm trying to bind back to my TemplatedControl to get the DP's that style it.

In WPF I would basically do like `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:CONTROL_NAME}}, Path=WHATEVER_STYLE}` but in WinRT I can't get back to the parent control.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The one way I found was sticking the control with the styles in the Tag and pushing it down the tree. I hate this approach though